# Swift code optimisation. How to monitor CPU usage for each function in Xcode

Tags: performance, swift, optimization, resources, cpu

Some parts of my app works a little bit slow. I wonder if there is a way to monitor CPU usage for each function or closure in Xcode? So I can understand, which part has to be optimised.

Thank you!

Comment: Use [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/).

Comment: Adam, I've tried but which of instrument should I use. And still I can't manage to start monitoring. All the instruments added stay idle.

Comment: Use `Time Profiler`. Check out some tutorials online. Stack Overflow is not a tutorial website, it is more for specific problems.